# Cannot install python-poppler

Tags: python, cmake, poppler

I am trying to install python-poppler by using pip install python-poppler. I am using a Jupyter Notebook on Windows.

When I run this, I receive the following errors:

```
 RuntimeError: CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: poppler.cpp.modules
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-poppler
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

      RuntimeError: CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: poppler.cpp.modules
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure
```

I have Cmake installed. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What you have posted is a summary, the actual error is going to be further up in the output

Comment: "I have Cmake installed." - How exactly have you installed CMake? Have you used pip for that?

Comment: Yes, I used pip to install Cmake!